# Showing error in yarn start command says This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; try to make an install to update your resolutions

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json

The error shown when yarn start command is given

Error details:

```
Internal Error: confusion@workspace:.: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; try to make an install to update your resolutions
    at J.getCandidates (C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:2:276872)
    at i.getCandidates (C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:2:266282)
    at C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:2:286432    at C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:57:349928
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.exports (C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:57:349910)
    at o (C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:57:349611)
    at C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:57:349684
    at C:\Users\risha\Desktop\Front-End Web Development with React\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:57:349727
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }

}
```

I have tried adding

```
"scripts":{
  "start":"react-scripts start"
}
```

But no change in the error.

Answer (score 9):

Cross-posting from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722201/yarn-command-yarn-import-error-this-package-doesnt-seem-to-be-present-in-you/66734056#66734056):

The problem in here seems to be an existing `yarn.lock` file inside of one of the workspaces. Deleting it solves the problem.

#### More info:

Example: 3 workspaces: 2 create-react-app (`app`, `home`) and one shared component: (`components`)

[image: folder strcuture]

Inside the `component` folder a lingering `yarn.lock` file exists. Remove it.

[image]

Also check that:

1. All your workspaces have `"private:true"` in each of their `package.json` (same level as `name`, `private`, `source`).
2. Check that you have added your workspaces inside a `"workspaces"` key in the main `package.json`
3. When you're executing `yarn workspaces myworkspace` `myworkspace` matches the name of your workspace in its `package.json`. In my case, the name of the workspace inside the `components` folder is called `@schon/components`, so I need to address it as `yarn worksapces @schon/components` instead.

Comment: I love when after fighting with something for 20 minutes the perfect SO answer pops up

Comment: If only it were 20 minutes...

Comment: Caught this issue while upgrading from v1 to berry, to make it easier to search for I looked for exactly: @workspace:.: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; run "yarn install" to update the lockfile

Comment: For anyone else who gets to this question/answer from searching, when using NPM you can delete `package-lock.json` to fix the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It means a certain package is not installed, and you need to install it.

- Try running `yarn install` to install the required packages.
- If this does not work, try deleting the `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install` again.
- If it fails, delete both `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` file and run `yarn install`.

Comment: Deleting `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` caused this problem for me in the first place.  Suggest renaming instead of deleting.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove node_modules by installing this package globally

> yarn add global rimraf

then remove the node
the -> rimraf node_moules
then remove the yarn.lock the install it by  yarn