# Yarn - Command yarn import error: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; try to make an install to update your resolutions

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm looking for using yarn and npm together in my project and if I find `yarn` useful for my particular case, I could move my project to use `yarn` only.

Nevertheless, I'm getting the following error with `$yarn import`:

```
local:project_middleware jgil$ yarn import

Internal Error: project-middleware@workspace:.: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; try to make an install to update your resolutions
at J.getCandidates (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:325115)
at i.getCandidates (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:314232)
at /Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:335605
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Ae.resolveEverything (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:335321)
at async Ae.applyLightResolution (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:357937)
at async Ae.restoreInstallState (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:357667)
at async Ke.execute (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:98394)
at async Ke.validateAndExecute (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2:626801)
at async j.run (/Users/jgil/Development/BerserkerStudio/project_middleware/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:17:3854)
```

I have already run `$yarn set version berry` and tried out again and again with different combinations of removing the `node_modules` directory, running `npm install`, etc. and nothing gets to make it work... no idea of what's missing.

Could it be a problem with either the version of Node.js or any other component I'm using?

Comment: Did you run `yarn install`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem in here seems to be an existing `yarn.lock` file inside of one of the workspaces. Deleting it solves the problem.

#### More info:

Example: 3 workspaces: 2 create-react-app (`app`, `home`) and one shared component: (`components`)

[image: folder strcuture]

Inside the `component` folder a lingering `yarn.lock` file exists. Remove it.

[image]

Also check that:

1. All your workspaces have `"private": true` in each of their `package.json` (same level as `name`, `private`, `source`).
2. Check that you have added your workspaces inside a `"workspaces"` key in the main `package.json`
3. When you're executing `yarn workspaces myworkspace` `myworkspace` matches the name of your workspace in its `package.json`. In my case, the name of the workspace inside the `components` folder is called `@schon/components`, so I need to address it as `yarn worksapces @schon/components` instead.

Comment: Removing the yarn.lock files from my workspace directories resolved this for me. Answer deserves to be accepted!

Answer (score 8):

The same error appears for me, I discovered that I had added `.yarnrc.yml` by mistake. After deleting the file and its reference in `yarn-berry.cjs` I had the solution and the project ran[image]

Comment: I had the opposite problem where I was forgetting to copy the `.yarnrc.yml` file into Docker before running `yarn install`. I was spending so much time trying to figure out why Yarn was not saving a certain package to disk, and that is why (Yarn only saves to the `node_modules` folder if you specifically tell it to now, in Yarn version 2); your mention of `.yarnrc.yml` finally made me realize my mistake. :|

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having this issue: I had the same problem after downgrading from Yarn 3 to Yarn 1.

I had `"packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"` set in the monorepo root package.json, but had `"packageManger": "yarn@3.41"` still set in each of my package's package.json

After removing the `packageManager` field from each package's package.json the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after working with different branches. I just `git rebase main`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is only one `yarn.lock` file present at root.

Answer (score -2):

I have met the same case .

remove the yarnrc.yml and it worked .

ls -a

rm .yarnrc.yml

it is worked for me .

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67307502/2227743).